# pandas конвертация нужного типа данных с игнорированием ненужных типов

Tags: python, pandas

Есть `.xlsx` файл.

Первая колонка - нумерация строк (это ещё до считывания в `dataframe`, я не путаю эти понятия). Первая строка - имена колонок.

Заполнен данными типа `hex`, `int`, `str` либо `None` (пустые клетки).

Надо:

1. считать данные
2. конвертировать `hex` в `int`
3. всё кроме `hex` игнорируем (ставим пустую клетку, например)

Пока что делаю так:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='first_sheet')  
df1 = df.iloc[1:28,1:11].map(lambda x : int(x, 16))        # вручную выбрал блок данных, без первой строки и первой колонки
print(df1)
```

Сейчас облегчает задачу, то что нужные мне `hex` данные стоят кУчно, но скоро таких файлов будут тысячи, и посмотреть на каждый лист каждого файла будет нереально. Конвертация `hex` в `int` это несложно, но для автоматической обработки многочисленных пустых клеток и ненужных `string` надо написать лямбду побольше. И вот тут я немного потерялся.

Comment: Чем отличается hex от int на листе? есть префикс вроде 0x или что-то еще?

Comment: если есть префикс то можно фильтровать по регулярному выражению

Comment: вот такое 0x80 - hex

Comment: 'фильтровать по регулярному выражению' точно не вариант, надо фильтровать по типу данных.

Comment: Тип данных у `0x80` - str, отличить его по типу данных от `aaa` не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так, например:

```
def cnv(val):
    try:
        res = eval(val)
        return res
    except:
        return np.nan
res = df.map(cnv)
```

на примере данных от `@Алексей Р` получим:

```
    Col1   Col2
0    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN  291.0
4  128.0    NaN
```

Comment: ребята, всем спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Без образца данных сложно понять картинку.
По префиксу '0x' делаем булев массив (маску) и инвертируем: где ненужные данные, будет True. Меняем все эти ячейки на None. Преобразуем все данные в int по основанию 16 с помощью `.map()` или `.applymap()`, указав опциональный аргумент `na_action='ignore'`, чтобы не обрабатывать NaN (таким образом, производительность будет выше и не возникнет ошибок преобразования).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [7898, '123', None, 'aaa', '0x80'], 'Col2': [10, None, 'bbb', '0x123', 0]})
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('0x', na=False))] = None
df = df.map(int, base=16, na_action='ignore')  # до версии Pandas 2.1.0 используйте .applymap()
print(df)
```

```
    Col1   Col2
0    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN  291.0
4  128.0    NaN
```